# How to fix microphone accessing being blocked in an iframe which only affects Google Chrome?

Tags: iframe, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have a version of the web chat based off Sample 6 (Cognitive Services speech - https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js) with some additional styling such as colours.

I have embedded the page into an iframe on a SharePoint 365 site and when I attempt to click on the microphone, I get a permission denied error. This only happens in Google Chrome; Firefox has no issues with providing microphone access and accepting speech input.

From searching, the allow attribute needs to be added to the iframe tags which I have done so to allow microphone access, however this appears to have no impact as I still receive the same error message: permission denied. I have tried adding the site into the allow attribute which also made no difference.

I have tried adding the site to trusted sites as well to no avail. Navigating to the web chat itself and using microphone there has no issues. Chrome asks for permission for the microphone to be used and the chat accepts speech input.

This issue only happens in Google Chrome and not in Firefox.

This is the iframe code:

```html
<iframe src="https://.........../webchat.html" allow="microphone;" style="min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;" width="800" height="500"></iframe>
```

I expect the result to be similar to Firefox where the browser asks for microphone access and the chat to start accepting speech input.

What I get is the following error message in the console:

2019-08-02T11:15:00.146Z | AudioSourceErrorEvent | metadata: {} | audioSourceId: 21F72644922849E3AA429BDDB1D44D70 | error: Error occurred during microphone initialization: NotAllowedError: Permission denied

Chrome does not ask for microphone access permission. How can I have the web chat working in an iframe using Chrome browser?

Comment: Does it work in an iframe outside of SharePoint? Like even a locally hosted .html page? Everything else that I would have you check looks good. I don't have a repro right now, but I will try.

Comment: @DanaV were you able to solve this issue?